# MyObject may not respond to message '-Foo'. (Noob) Objective-C question

Tags: objective-c, casting, nsmutablearray

Yet another C#/.NET guy trying to learn Objective-C with big dreams of making millions with an iPhone app :)

Ok, I'm sure this question stems from me being so used to static typed languages, and therefore am having a tough time adjusting, but here's my issue. Let's assume I have a class called MyObect:

**MyObject.h**

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{

}

-(void)Foo;

@end
```

**MyObject.m**

```
#import "MyObject.h"
@implementation MyObject

-(void)Foo
{
  //do something fooey
}

@end
```

Now I'm trying to mess with an NSMutableArray of these objects, so in my main I fill an array of these objects something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
{
   MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc]init];
   [array addObject:obj];
}
```

Nothing fancy. Now, however, I was trying to pull out the first one of the array, and call the foo method. So, here's where I'm getting confused. I've tried this:

```
MyObject *obj = [array objectAtIndex:1];
[obj Foo];
```

**and while this works, I get a warning of MyObject may not respond to message**. So, I figured, ok, let me cast it:

```
MyObject *obj = (MyObject *)[array objectAtIndex:1];
[obj Foo];
```

and that also gives me the warning.

I guess my question is a fundamental question as to how you store items in a collection, and how you pull them out and still retain the object's type. Again, I'm coming from a .NET background, so maybe my thinking is fundamentally flawed, so if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

**EDIT**: My original code did in fact have the asterisk in the cast (without it you get a compile error). It still shows the warning though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not give a warning, given that you include the asterisk as you describe in a comment to another answer. In fact, I think the cast is unnecessary -- even the version without the cast should not give a warning.

Make sure that the header file MyObject.h is #imported at the start of the file where you are trying to call your method. The warning that you get is typical of cases where you have forward-declared a class with `@class MyObject` but not included the header with `#import "MyObject.h"`.

BTW, in Objective-C one usually starts method names with a lowercase letter, as in Java.

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, it does build and run successfully, however I get a warning from the (XCode) compiler. I could just ignore it, but I just get the feeling I'm doing something wrong. (Thanks for the info about method-naming practices.)

Comment: I just double checked, and yes, the header file is included at the top using #import. (Without it, I get compile time errors that don't even let it build). I still get the warning though. (I feel like sucha freaking noob!!) Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Okay, well, there's still a good change the warning might be related to this. #import order can cause subtle errors. XCode has an option to view the output of the preprocessor (I forgot where), try that and verify that the declaration of MyObject is present above where you try to call the method.

Comment: See my answer. Stupid rookie mistake. Forgot to add the declaration to the header file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change your casting line to:

```
MyObject *obj = (MyObject *)[array objectAtIndex:1];
```

The missing `*` is the problem.

Comment: That was actually a typo on my part in the question. My mistake. My code *DOES* have the asterisk there, but I still get the warning.

Comment: Make sure you #import "MyObject.h" in the file where you are doing your array processing.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I feel like a total moron right now :( I forgot to add the method declaration to the header file. The fact that both of you kept stressing that I need to make sure I'm importing the header file, made me realize this. Thanks both of you for your help.